# Google Geocode API Address Formatting United States

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

This question is similar in spirit to. http: //stackoverflow.com/questions/7764244/correct-address-format-to-get-the-most-accurate-results-from-google-geocoding-ap

I've read the FAQ on the google geocode developers guidelines and it states that the suggested format for addresses is based off the country's postal service.  In some of my testing this is not always working and sometimes I'm seeing better results putting the street at the end of query.

example being: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=+3700%20W%20FLAMINGO%20RD++LAS%20VEGAS+NV
This returns zero results, but swapping road to the end returns a correct result:
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=++LAS%20VEGAS+NV+3700%20W%20FLAMINGO%20RD

On top of that if I include the zipcode (89103) to the second request, that one will return no results as well.

Can anyone help me to understand what the appropriate format should look like for US addresses?

Thanks much!
-Chris

Answer (score 0):

The answer you can find in this document

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#geocoder_queryformat

> **How should I format my geocoder queries to maximise the number of successful requests?**
>
> Specify addresses in accordance with the format used by the national postal service of the country concerned.
>
> Do not specify additional address elements such as business names, unit numbers, floor numbers, or suite numbers that are not included in the address as defined by the postal service of the country concerned.
>
> Use the street number of a premise in preference to the building name where possible.
>
> Use street number addressing in preference to specifying cross streets where possible.
>
> Do not provide 'hints' such as nearby landmarks